# Paperclip photo upload fails in IE8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, paperclip-validation

I'm using paperclip to upload image in my app. The validation I've is :

```
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpg','image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/tiff', 'image/gif']
```

Everything works well in firefox, chorme and IE9. But in **IE8**, I get an error - 
     "*Photos image content type Invalid format !!!*"

Any solution or clue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

says it needs extra image format `image/pjpeg` in content type i.e. `:content_type => ['image/pjpeg']`

Below will be helpful for sure.

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/11/26/paperclip-validates_attachment_content_type-always-fails-in-ie-6-and-7-for-jepg-and-png-image/

http://blog.siyelo.com/tip-of-the-day-mime-types-for-paperclip-ie8

Answer (score 2):

You can try this instead: `content_type => /image/`

Comment: Hi Codeglot, as you suggested I did this : `validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['/image/jpg','/image/jpeg', '/image/png', '/image/tiff', '/image/gif']`. But now the photo upload does not work in any browser. Did I missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood the previous answer. What he was suggesting was that you use a regular expression on containing the word 'image' instead of adding the forward slash in the front. So your modified code would look like this:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /image/
```

The // means you are using a regular expression for the content type instead of being explicit by each element in the array. The above would search the whole content_type string and match image, or you can be a little more strict and use:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /^image/
```

which means that the string has to begin with the word 'image', which it should. This should help you through IE as well.